# Two-way binding to a dataset - updating the database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, binding

Okay, so I'm fairly new to WPF and data binding, but I've searched and searched and can't seem to find an answer to this.

I have a database (called Inventory), and a dataset (called DevicesDataSet).  What I'm trying to do is bind the dataset to a listbox, so that a specific device from the Devices table of the DevicesDataSet can be selected, and have its properties displayed in a TextBox for editing.

The following is the XAML I have so far:

```
<Window x:Class="Inventory.SignOutDevice"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SignOutDevice" Height="339" Width="392" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Inventory" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <my:DevicesDataSet x:Key="devicesDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="devicesViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Devices, Source={StaticResource devicesDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource devicesViewSource}">
    <ListBox Height="237" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listBox1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="Selected">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Make}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Margin="223,267,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Make, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Whenever a device is selected and a property is edited (I'm only displaying one property at the moment), the listbox is updated, but the dataset (database?) doesn't seem to be.  That is, when I leave the form and then come back to it, the listbox returns to its original state.

So I guess the question is: how do I make these changes persist/write to the database?

Edit: Derp, here's the updated backend C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
namespace Inventory
{
    public partial class SignOutDevice : Window
    {
        DevicesDataSet devicesDataSet = null;
        Inventory.DevicesDataSetTableAdapters.DevicesTableAdapter devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter = null;
        public SignOutDevice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            devicesDataSet = ((Inventory.DevicesDataSet)(this.FindResource("devicesDataSet")));
            devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter = new Inventory.DevicesDataSetTableAdapters.DevicesTableAdapter();
            devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter.Fill(devicesDataSet.Devices);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource devicesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("devicesViewSource")));
            devicesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            devicesDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter.Update(devicesDataSet.Tables["Devices"].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Deleted));
            devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter.Update(devicesDataSet.Tables["Devices"].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent));
            devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter.Update(devicesDataSet.Tables["Devices"].Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Added));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.  Turns out the auto-generated Update() method in devicesDataSetDevicesTableAdapter didn't actually do anything.  Made a custom method with the Query Wizard and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the Output window to check for binding errors?  Because it looks to me like you have one.  The `TextBox` is bound to the `Make` property, but its `DataContext` is the `devicesViewSource` resource.  There's nothing associating it with the selected item in the `ListBox`.

A way to associate the two would be to assign the `ListBox` a name, and then set the binding on the `TextBox` to `{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=Make, Mode=TwoWay}`.

Comment: That part works just fine, and when I edit the TextBox, the ListBox is updated as well.  My issue isn't with the interface, but with the database not being updated.  Also, the ListBox already has a name: "listBox1".